# How to use Nexus' Prisma plugin crud with specific arguments

Tags: graphql, prisma, nexus-js

I have an `Advertiser` graphql type:

```js
type Advertiser {
  createdAt: DateTime!
  id: Int!
  isActive: Boolean!
  name: String!
  updatedAt: DateTime
}
```

Given the following mutation:

```js
mutationType({
  definition(t) {
    t.crud.createOneAdvertiser();
  }
});
```

Nexus generates this schema (as expected):

```js
input AdvertiserCreateInput {
  createdAt: DateTime!
  isActive: Boolean!
  name: String!
  updatedAt: DateTime
}

type Mutation {
  createOneAdvertiser(data: AdvertiserCreateInput!): Advertiser!
}
```

The thing is, what if I want to omit some of the args? For example, I don't want the client to pass `createdAt` or `updatedAt`. these columns should be resolved in the server.

See (partial) documentation here - https://nexusjs.org/docs/plugins/prisma/api#example-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet again, found the answer right after posting this question. Simply pass [computedInputs](https://nexusjs.org/docs/plugins/prisma/overview#publish-autogenerated-mutations-with-computed-input-values) like so:

```js
t.crud.createOneAdvertiser({
  computedInputs: {
    createdAt: () => DateTime.utc().toString(),
    updatedAt: () => null
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Great question Eliya.

If you're using Nexus to define your GraphQL types, you can use the [`objectType`](https://nexusjs.org/docs/api/object-type) to define your schema types. When paired with Prisma and nexus-plugin-prisma, you can use [`t.model`](https://nexusjs.org/docs/plugins/prisma/api#model-object-mapping) to map your schema types to your db models in your `objectType`. When defining your `objectType`, you can choose to omit some columns in your database models.

Here's an example Prisma model to demonstrate the concept:

```
model Post {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  title     String
  content   String?
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

When defining your `objectType`, you can include the the `updatedAt` column:

```
import { objectType } from 'nexus'

const Post = objectType({
  name: 'Post',
  definition(t) {
    t.model.id()
    t.model.title()
    t.model.content()
    t.model.published()
    t.model.author()
    t.model.updatedAt()
  }
})

export default Post
```

`updatedAt`, in this example, will be resolved by the GraphQL server/Prisma and your client won't be required to pass the argument despite being included in the `inputType` generated by Nexus.

I hope this answers your question. If you need any further clarifications let me know.

Comment: Yet again, thanks for the help. But what if we're talking about a column that is not `updatedAt`? let's say I have a type of Account. An account has a "credits" column. I want to read it, but not write on it. How would you approach this situation?

Comment: You can make a column nullable by using the `?` operator in your model. Nexus  `inputTypes` generated will make field nullable too meaning you won't have to include the field when creating/updating a record.. The field will be readable and writable(if you wish to write to it). 

Would you like to make a column readonly?

Comment: It should be readonly. Meaning, only the server would be able to write on it (e.g auth token, credits, etc)